# PHP preg_match range

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to use preg_match to match numbers 1 - 21. How can I do this using preg_match? If the number is greater than 21 I don't want to match anything.

```
example preg_match('([0-9][0-1]{0,2})', 'Johnathan 21');
```

Comment: I don't think you need to limit valid solutions to regex only, other approaches (e.g. capturing `[0-9]{1,2}` in regexp and validating afterwards) might be easier. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/22/603788.aspx

Comment: @DCoder: This should be an answer.

Comment: True. I thought I would much simpler to use regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copied from [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056440/php-preg-match-range#comment12869026_10056440):

I suggest matching simply `([0-9]{1,2})` (maybe wrapped in `\b`, based on input format) and filtering the numeric value later, in PHP code.

See also [Raymond Chen's thoughts on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/22/603788.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I used '\d+' to match the number into an array then i validated that it was between 1 - 21.

Answer (score 3):

Literally:

```
preg_match('~ (1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21)$~', 'Johnathan 21');
```

But maybe this is more nifty:

```
preg_match('~ ([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[01])$~', 'Johnathan 21');
```

Comment: This example will match every number.

Comment: which one? and for what? should I make it greedy?

Comment: Yes. I want to make this greedy.

Comment: @hakre: Both expressions will happily match `"11111111111"`, and that's not the intent. It needs to be wrapped inside `\D`.

Comment: @Jon: preg_match does only match once. If you take `11111111111` it specifically matches `1` (the first one), which is a correct number to be matched, it's within 1 and 21. So actually that's not the wrong expression. Okay maybe it matches `11`. Which is ok as well as between 1 and 21. Probably OP should specify if numbers are separated by some specific characters. As this is not documented, I assume that numbers aren't separated at all.

Comment: @hakre: My point exactly. It will match `1`, which is technically correct, but it's certainly not what the OP expects. `1111111111` as a whole is greater than 21, so should not be matched. At least that's how I understand it.

Comment: @Jon: Sure, I added the delimiting characters: one space in front and end of string at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could stablish an incremental filter like this example for TCP ports (altougth includes port number 0), like the previous answer:

```
preg_match('/^([0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])$/', '62000');
```